# could not resolve property: PropertyName of: Class error in NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate first time and in this line it throws exception for me

```
var total = session
                    .QueryOver<Comment>().Where(p => p.Entry.Author == username)
                    .ToRowCountQuery()
                    .FutureValue<int>();

                var results = session
                    .QueryOver<Comment>().Where(p => p.Entry.Author == username)
                    .Fetch(x => x.Entry).Eager()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Posted).Desc()
                    .Skip(skip)
                    .Take(take)
                    .List();
```

The Exception is

> could not resolve property: Entry.Author of: FunnelWeb.Model.Comment

I guess, the problem is that `Entry` object doesn't loaded here. How can I do that trick with Nhibernate?

Comment: could you post the hbm ( or other mapping ) for Comment ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QueryOver is just a strongly-typed wrapper for Criteria, and doesn't allow implicit deep references.

You'd have to use:

```
session.QueryOver<Comment>()
       .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Entry)
       .Where(x => x.Author == username)
```

Or you can use `Query<>` instead (LINQ) which will work with the syntax you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to JoinAlias or JoinQueryOver. I have an example below on how to use Future queries...

```
Entry entryAlias = null;

var q = session.QueryOver<Comment>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Entry, () => entryAlias)
    .Where(() => entryAlias.Author == username);

var totalFuture = q.ToRowCountQuery().FutureValue<int>(); //ToRowcountQuery clones the query, we can reuse it for results

var resultsFuture = q
    //.Fetch(x => x.Entry).Eager() //already joined
    .OrderBy(x => x.Posted).Desc()
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take)
    .Future<Comment>();

var results = resultsFuture.ToList(); //both future queries are executed in the same batch 
var total = totalFuture.Value;
```